# Provider for jakarta.activation.spi.MimeTypeRegistryProvider cannot be found

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

After having to change from javax.mail to jakarta.mail, my application fails to start because of "Provider for jakarta.activation.spi.MimeTypeRegistryProvider cannot be found". What is a MimeTypeRegistryProvider, and how can I add one ?

Comment: What is your environment, which jarkarta library did you use?

Answer (score 3):

Add [Angus Mail Provider](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.angus/angus-mail) to your classpath.

For maven, add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
  <artifactId>angus-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the angus-activation-1.1.0.jar and angus-mail-1.1.0.jar packages (or the most recent versions of these files, completely depends on what you're working with."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: version 1.1.0 didn't work for me, version 2.0.0 did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I use the `Java17`.And I solve the problem.This may cause by the java version.

In `Java9` use the modules, some modules may not load by default.And we need import it.

For maven, please add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting issue during upgrade JDK version 11 to 17 and Spring boot 2.X to 3.X

> Please use these dependencies to solve the problem:

```
implementation 'com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:2.0.1'
```

Comment: What repository has activation 2.0.1? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/javax.activation

Comment: No repo for javax.activation for this version 2.0.1. javax deprecated on new Spring boot 3.x. now we are using jakarta instead of javax.

Please use this repo for 2.0.1: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail/2.0.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/jakarta.activation/2.0.1

Comment: The Jigsaw-Project "outsourced" (among other things) internal sun-classes to external dependencies. The activation API can now be found under the group ID "jakarta.activation" (no 'sun' anymore).

Consider to use the Jakarta bill of materials in order to hava always matching versionising of all Jakarta dependencies: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.platform/jakarta.jakartaee-bom (current stable version uses jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.0)

Same with the Mail API - see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.mail/jakarta.mail-api

Comment: And YES - you still need a PROVIDER - and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.angus/angus-mail as mentioned by @baiyangliu does the job :)