# Spring Boot 3: Provider for jakarta.activation.spi.MailcapRegistryProvider cannot be found

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I get an error upon sending email in a Spring Boot 3 application.

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: java.lang.RuntimeException: Provider for jakarta.activation.spi.MailcapRegistryProvider cannot be found
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:491)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:361)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356)
```

We are using JavaMailSender to send the email.

I wave the below dependency already.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Here's my code:

```java
private final JavaMailSender mailSender;
    
    private void sendEmail () {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    
        MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, false, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        messageHelper.setTo("testemail@test.com");
        messageHelper.setSubject("test subject");
        messageHelper.setText("sample html email content", true);
        mailSender.send(message);
    }
```

Comment: Related: [Provider for jakarta.activation.spi.MimeTypeRegistryProvider cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74900271/provider-for-jakarta-activation-spi-mimetyperegistryprovider-cannot-be-found)

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same issue during upgrade JDK version 11 to 17 and Spring boot 2.X to 3.X

> Please use these dependencies to resolve the problem:

```
implementation 'com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:2.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This implementation of mail API

Comment: For code formatting in the site, you can check [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/16702058)

Answer (score -2):

@Service
public class MailServiceImpl implements
Mail Service {

```
private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
public MailServiceImpl (JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
}


@Override
public void send (String receiver, String sender, String message, String filenameAndLocation) {
    MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        @Override
        public void prepare (MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            messageHelper.setTo(receiver);
            messageHelper.setFrom(sender);
            messageHelper.setSubject("test subject");
            messageHelper.setText(message);
        }
    };
    this.javaMailSender.send(preparator);
}
```

}

Write your service class same like this hope it will help you

Comment: This doesn't help, what is the cause for the error that is occuring to me

Comment: Can you show me. Your full code